# Creating a associative array in php from a larger multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Im having trouble extracting some information from a large array and placing it in a smaller array, the large array i have is as follows;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BlanketBrand] => Array
                (
                    [BlanketBrandID] => 125
                    [BlanketBrandName] => Neptune
                    [BlanketBrandActive] => Y
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [BlanketBrand] => Array
                (
                    [BlanketBrandID] => 126
                    [BlanketBrandName] => King Size
                    [BlanketBrandActive] => Y
                )

        )

)
```

What i would like is to create an array from this with just the BlanketBrandID as the key and the BlanketBrandName as the value

```
array(
    125 => Neptune,
    126 => King Size
)
```

Something like that so its easier for me to work with.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a very simple foreach loop:

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'BlanketBrand' => [
            'BlanketBrandID' => 125,
            'BlanketBrandName' => 'Neptune',
            'BlanketBrandActive' => 'Y'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'BlanketBrand' => [
            'BlanketBrandID' => 126,
            'BlanketBrandName' => 'King Size',
            'BlanketBrandActive' => 'Y'
        ]
    ]
];

$new_array = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $new_array[ $item['BlanketBrand']['BlanketBrandID'] ] = $item['BlanketBrand']['BlanketBrandName'];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

See example [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/WyNJQ9hv36e5vJyb).

You can also accomplish this with [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$new_array = array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a[ $b['BlanketBrand']['BlanketBrandID'] ] = $b['BlanketBrand']['BlanketBrandName'];

    return $a;
}, []);
```

See example [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/u9v6bIdJwuX50f19).

Comment: @CodeCodeCodeCode Also provided an example using `array_reduce()`, but ultimately it boils down to the same thing.